# I want to change the color of a single cell in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to change the color of a single cell in a `JTable` when I click a button.

See an example in the image below

[image]

I tried to achieve that purpose with this code:

```
drig_rdv.getModel().setValueAt("Anouar", 0, 2);
    MyCellRenderer mcr = new MyCellRenderer();
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < drig_rdv.getColumnCount(); columnIndex ++) {

        drig_rdv.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(mcr);
    }
```

This is my cell renderer:

```
 public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {
public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    cellComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color.YELLOW);
    return cellComponent;
   }
}
```

Comment: Look at `Component.setBackground(Color)`. Specifically, you need to be looking at the `prepareRenderer` method of your JTable.

Comment: And I want you to post code of what you have tried so far and explain what your problem is. Urgently, please!

Comment: drig_rdv.getModel().setValueAt("Anouar", 0, 2);
        MyCellRenderer mcr = new MyCellRenderer();
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < drig_rdv.getColumnCount(); columnIndex ++) {

            drig_rdv.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(mcr);
        }

Comment: Edit your post and put the code there. Not in the comments here, please.

Comment: the post is edited

Comment: Also, next time don't write something like "I want an answer" and especially not "urgently". You're asking for help, not ordering us to help you.